# Plotting rosbag topics in a single plot

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a (large) rosbag.
I want to plot a few of these topics (in the same plot).
I don't need any playback feature.

I can load the bag with rqt and plot topics, one topic per plot. But can I have more topics in the same plot?
Another disadvantage is, that it requires a running roscore.

Are there any other tools that allows me to extract selected topics from a rosbag and plot them?
Bonus points if I can have a tool that:

1. does not require a roscore running
2. runs on Windows as well

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323833/plotting-rosbag-topics-in-a-single-plot/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2019-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't run on Windows (or at least, not bare Windows, perhaps WSL), but take a look at [PlotJuggler](http://wiki.ros.org/plotjuggler).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-23**:
There are other tools that support multiple plots btw, such as [rqt_multiplot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_multiplot).

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2019-06-05**:
Indeed... PlotJuggler doesn't require roscore to load rosbags, but it is not currently supported on Windows